# UITextChecker for ru_RU in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextchecker

I am trying to implement autocomplete for Russian words in **Swift 2.0** and I faced with the following problem.

I've implemented the following code to test how **UITextChecker()** works:

```
    let textChecker = UITextChecker()
    let getAvailableLanguages = UITextChecker.availableLanguages()
    print(getAvailableLanguages)
    let partial = "leo"
    let completions = textChecker.completionsForPartialWordRange(NSRange(0..<partial.utf16.count), inString: partial,language: "en_US")
    let completions2 = textChecker.guessesForWordRange(NSRange(0..<partial.utf16.count), inString: partial, language: "en_US")
    print(completions)
    print(completions2)
```

This code prints the following result and this result looks good for me:

List of languages:

```
[ru_RU, en_CA, pt_BR, it_IT, ko_KR, nb_NO, de_DE, en_GB, sv_SE, en_AU, en_SG, es_MX, pt_PT, en_IN, fr_FR, es_ES, nl_NL, tr_TR, fi_FI, pl_PL, en_US, da_DK]
```

completionsForPartialWordRange:

```
Optional([leonine, leopard, leopardess,leopardesses, leopards, leotard, leotarded, leotards])
```

guessesForWordRange:

```
Optional([Leo, lei, lek, lea, led, lee, leg, let, leu, lev, lex, lao, loo, geo, cleo, oleo, lego, leto, leon])
```

After it I've implemented the same code for **ru_RU**

```
    let textChecker = UITextChecker()
    let partial = "кош"
    let completions = textChecker.completionsForPartialWordRange(NSRange(0..<partial.utf16.count), inString: partial,language: "ru_RU")
    let completions2 = textChecker.guessesForWordRange(NSRange(0..<partial.utf16.count), inString: partial, language: "ru_RU")
    print(completions)
    print(completions2)
```

But `completionsForPartialWordRange` always returns empty array for `ru_RU`:

```
Optional([])
```

**Actual result** for `"кош"` should be at least `"кошка"` but there is an **empty array**.

Despite this guessesForWordRange works fine for `ru_RU`:

```
Optional([каш, ко, кол, коб, код, кое, кож, коз, кои, кой, кок, ком, кон, коп, кор, кос, кот, коф, кою, куш, кэш, нош, шок, ковш, коуш, коша, коше, коши, кошм, кошт, кошу])
```

I've tried to use different Russian words but I always get empty array from `completionsForPartialWordRange` method.
Do I have a mistake in code or it is some known Apple bug? How to get completions for `ru_RU` with `completionsForPartialWordRange` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help somebody I will provide Apple answer from their bug report service.

After I wrote to Apple I've received the following answer:

> Engineering has determined that your bug report is a
>   duplicate of another issue and will be closed.
>
> The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was
>   duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of
>   the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of
>   the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title,
>   state, product and rank.

Unfortunately there were no more additional information.

### UPDATE

Fixed in IOS 10.1